# Is an artifact generated by a software under the same license if not explicitly stated?

Tags: software, open-source-software

The current example is to generate an audio file with spoken text using a speech synthesizer and a voice, which both are licensed under a proprietary or open source license.

Assuming the license does not explicitly state about the license of the generated artifacts, which legal status will the artifacts have?

Comment: In general, *output* of a software program is not bound by the license of the software itself, *unless* if the output includes significant protectable parts of the software in the output itself. See [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output (audio recording of spoken text) is obviously a derived work of the unspoken text. With current high-quality voices, using samples recorded by a human speaker and not just algorithms, your output also most likely contains large parts of the voice itself, and would therefore be a derived work. In that case, you would need a license to create the derived work (the spoken text), and a license to make copies of the derived work (distributing the spoken text).

If the voice synthesizer is plainly algorithmic, you wouldn't need a license. If there is a debate and things go to court, you would probably need some expert witnesses to testify whether the spoken test *is* indeed a derived work or not, because it might not be obvious.

So you'd want a license permitting your use to be on the safe side. Especially if you think your spoken text could be a derived work of the voice.

Answer (score 0):

### The software

The licence on the software has no impact on the output. Even if you are using the software illegally, that doesn’t affect the output - if you write a novel using an illegal Microsoft Word, you own the copyright.

### The input

However, your rights to the output *are* affected by the status of the input.

If there is no creativity in the operation, that is, the output is always the same for the same input, then the output *is* the input as far as the copyright is concerned - it’s just a change of format like translating from a jpeg to a bmp.

However, if there is some creative input, for example, if the output changes by changing parameters, then the output is a *derivative* work with its own copyright.

In both cases, however, you have to have permission to make copies - because you own the copyright, have a licence or it’s fair use/dealing.